# Failed to terminate ec-2 instance: How to modify its 'disableApiTermination' attribute from EC2 Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I opened a free tier instance for some practice.

I tried to terminate it, as I've done many times successfully.

But upon selecting `Terminate instance` from the dropdown;

[image]

I got the following error:

```
Failed to terminate the instance <instance id>
The instance '<instance id>' may not be terminated. Modify its 'disableApiTermination' instance attribute and try again.
```

Where can I find the `disableApiTermination` attribute?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination)

> To disable termination protection for a running or stopped instance
>
> 1. Select the instance, and choose **Actions, Instance Settings, Change Termination Protection**.
> 2. Choose Yes, Disable.

[image]

[image]

Using AWS CLI you can use this command

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <instance-id> --no-disable-api-termination
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**: you need to disable api termination protection by changing instance attribute, I'll demonstrate how to do it with aws api.
([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html) attached)

```
instance_id=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
               --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=instance-name-example" \
               --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId[]" \
               --output text)
               
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $instance_id  --no-disable-api-termination
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable/disable the instance termination by using aws cli.

To enable protection:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <instance-id> --disable-api-termination
```

To disable protection:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <instance-id> --no-disable-api-termination
```

Comment: The question states how to disable from "...from EC2 Dashboard..." not CLI.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to disable both these options :

Select your EC2 instance  > Actions > Instance settings  > change termination protection > uncheck the enabled option

Select your EC2 instance  > Actions > Instance settings  > change stop protection > uncheck the enabled

[image]